# Proving that every patch in a surface $M$ in $R^3$ is proper.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, surfaces

**Problem**

Prove that if $\mathbf{y}:E\to M$ is a proper patch, then $\mathbf{y}$ carries open sets in $E$ to open sets in $M$. Deduce that if $\mathbf{x}:D \to M$ is an arbitrary patch, then the image $\mathbf{x}(D)$ is an open set in $M$. (Hint: To prove the latter assertion, use Cor 3.3.)
Finally, prove that every patch $\mathbf{x}:D\to M$ in a surface $M$in $R^3$ is proper. (Hint: use the above to note that $(\mathbf{x}^{-1}\mathbf{y})\mathbf{y}^{-1}$ is continuous and agrees with $\mathbf{x}^{-1}$ on an open set in $\mathbf{x}(D)$.)

First I will write down the definitions of some of the terms above, as they are given in the text.

**Definitions**

A patch $\mathbf{x}:D\to R^3$ is a one-to-one regular mapping of an open set $D$ of $R^2$ into $R^3$.

A proper patch is a patch for which the inverse function $\mathbf{x}^{-1}:\mathbf{x}(D)\to D$ is continuous.

A surface in $R^3$is a subset $M$ of $R^3$ such that for each point $\mathbf{p}$ of $M$ there exists a proper patch in $M$ whose image contains a neighborhood of $\mathbf{p}$ in $M$.

For a function $F:R^n\to M$, each patch **x** in $M$ gives a coordinate expression $\mathbf{x}^{-1}(F)$ for $F$.

A function $F:R^n\to M$ is differentiable provided all its coordinate expressions are differentiable in the usual Euclidean sense.

**3.3 Corollary**
If **x** and **y** are patches in a surface $M$ in $R^3$ whose images overlap, then the composite functions $\mathbf{x}^{-1}\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{y}^{-1}\mathbf{x}$ are differentiable mappings defined on open sets of $R^2$.

**My Question**

I don't know how to prove the first part.

Since **y**$^{-1}:\mathbf{y}(E)\to E$ is continuous, so by definition of continuity,  given an open set $O$ in $E$,${\mathbf{y}^{-1}}^{-1}(O)=\mathbf{y}(O)$ is open in $\mathbf{y}(E)$, but how can we guarantee that this is open in $M$ when $\mathbf{y}(E)$ is not the whole of $M$?

Moreover, taking this as given, how can I use Cor 3.3 to prove that the image of an arbitrary patch is open in $M$? And finally, how can these be used to show that every patch in a surface is proper?

I think I'm confused with the topology in surfaces, and this is inhibiting my thinking. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can write down a clear exposition of the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{y}:E\to M\subseteq\mathbb{R^3}$, $M$ a surface, be a proper patch. Then $\mathbf{y}^{-1}:\mathbf{y}(E)\to E$ is continuous. If $\mathbf{y}(E)$ contains any boundary points (i.e. it is not open), the function $\mathbf{y}^{-1}$ cannot be continuous, as a boundary point has no equivalent in an open set (every point in an open set has a neighbourhood, boundary points don't).

Next we note that if $\mathbf{x}:D\to M\subseteq\mathbb{R^3}$ is any patch, then $\mathbf{x}(D)$ is open by the definition of a surface. Let $p\in\mathbf{x}(D)$, then $p$ has a neighbourhood. As every point $p$ in $\mathbf{x}(D)$ has a neighbourhood, $\mathbf{x}(D)$ is open.

We can use Corollary 3.3 to prove the last part of the question. If a point $d\in D$ is part of a proper patch, we are done. If not, $\mathbf{x}(d)$ is part of a non-proper patch $\mathbf{x}$ and a proper patch $\mathbf{y}$ say. Because of Corollary 3.3, the point in $\mathbf{x}(d)$ is differentiable, and identifies a unique coordinate. $\mathbf{x}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}(d))=d$, and as $\mathbf{y}$ is proper, $\mathbf{x^{-1}y}(d)$ is continuous invertible.

This applies to every $d\in D$, and so means due to the duality of the differentiability of the composite functions in Corollary 3.3, every match is proper (as we could have equally used $\mathbf{y^{-1}x}$).

---

NOTE: Your question doesn't explicitly state $M$ is a surface at first, but I can't see how you can make progress otherwise. The last argument seems a bit dodgy - it does prove every point $d\in D$ is part of a proper patch, but it also might be part of a non-proper patch.

Comment: wrote "If a point $d\in D$ is part of a proper patch, we are done." How is this? How does $d\in D$ part of a proper patch imply $x^{-1}$ is continuous?

Comment: It says, "if $\mathbf{x}:D\to M\subseteq\mathbb{R^3}$ is any patch, then $\mathbf{x}(D)$ is open by the definition of a surface." How does this follow? The image points have neighborhoods that are contained in M but it is not obvious to me that they are contained in $x(D)$.

Comment: for your first  question, the OQ reads '  Finally, prove that every patch … is proper'. we don't need to prove $x^{-1}$ is continuous. for your second, the next line explains.

Comment: But that is the definition of "proper": the inverse is continuous. As for my second question, yes every point has a neighborhood but how do we know that the neighborhood is contained in $x(D)$?

Comment: because $x(D)$ is open (it contains all its limit points)

Comment: I thought that was what we were trying to prove: that x(D) is open. Also, again I ask "how does $d\in D$ part of a proper patch imply that $x^{-1}$ is continuous? Or are you saying that it doesn't have to be continuous? If that is the case, how do we know the patch is proper?

Comment: from the definitions in the question: 'A proper patch is a patch for which the inverse function ...is continuous.'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82995/discussion-between-gene-naden-and-jonmark-perry).

Answer (score 2):

This is only a topology problem. Since that $M\subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$, $M$ have a relative topology induced by the topology on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, $i.e.$, the open sets (or open neighborhood) $V$ on $M$ are open subsets on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ intersection $M$ ($V=U\cap \mathbb{R}^{3}$). If $\chi: D\rightarrow M$ is a proper patch then this is a continuous function one-to-one with continuos inverse (topologically speaking), then $\chi$ is a homeomorphism between $D$ and $M$. Then $\chi(E)$ is open if $E\subset D$ is open. Another way is, W.L.G. $\chi(E)\subset \chi(D)\cap\rho(F)$ with $\rho:F\rightarrow M$ other proper patch. By your corolary $(\rho^{-1}\circ\chi)(E)$ is open since $\rho^{-1}\circ\chi$ is a difeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and then $\rho\circ(\rho^{-1}\circ\chi)(E)$ is open on $M$, but $\rho\circ(\rho^{-1}\circ\chi)(E)=\chi(E)$ since $\rho$ and $\chi$ are one-to-one.