# Proper patch in the differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a question that coincides with this question.

[Proving that every patch in a surface $M$ in $R^3$ is proper.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327140/proving-that-every-patch-in-a-surface-m-in-r3-is-proper)

Prove that if $\mathbf{y}:E\to M$ is a proper patch, then $\mathbf{y}$ carries open sets in $E$ to open sets in $M$. Deduce that if $\mathbf{x}:D \to M$ is an arbitrary patch, then the image $\mathbf{x}(D)$ is an open set in $M$. (Hint: To prove the latter assertion, use Cor 3.3.)

The second part is clear if we prove the first part.

But, I think the first part was not completely solved. 
From the above link, the continuity of $\mathbf{y}^{-1}$ is broken at the boundary points. But, I can't assure this statement because this obey the subspace topology of "$\mathbf{y}(E)$". I think this problem lost some conditions.

Comment: How is the second part clear if we prove the first part? What are x and y in the corollary?